# How to add a DataSource Connection for PostgreSQL Database to Visual Studio 2013? (In order to use Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, visual-studio-2013

How/what kind of driver can I add to VS2013 to allow me connect to a PostgreSQL DB?

Ultimately I am trying to set up EF (Database first) model.

I've read to install npgsql in order to handle this.

This is what I've installed.

[image: This is what I've installed (via Nuget)]

This is what I see.

[image: This is what I see when trying to setup EF]

EDIT:
I installed psqlodbc_x64 (09_05) and I'm still having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to doing the above steps npgsql DDEX needs to be installed and setup in Visual Studio.